# peaks and valleys plotting in python with scipy and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to localize all peaks and valleys in a dataset. I found a solution that worked, but i then had to manually go in and change the column header to a name with just a single word. 
I wont to make a function that can handle several different csv file, and changing column names on all the file is a hassle

I have already tried to make the column header a variable, but pandas dont like that. I get the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'typ".

This is whats working, if i manually change the column name to "Data".

```py
 df = pd.read_csv(path,index_col=False).set_index('Timestamp')
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Data'])

df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.Data.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]['Data']
    df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.Data.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['Data']
```

This is more want i want to do:

```py
def peaks_valleys(path,typ,acc):

    df = pd.read_csv(path,index_col=False).set_index('Timestamp')
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[typ])

    n = acc #antall nummer sjekket før og etter

    df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.typ.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]][]typ
    df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.typ.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]][typ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `df.typ` is the same as `df['typ']`, so it is independent of the value of `typ` (which raises the `AttributeError`). It is better to avoid the `df.ColName`; instead using `df['ColName']` which is safer.

In addition, you can rename the columns in place using `.rename`, or pass them during the `read_csv` using `names=[...]`.

Try:

```
def peaks_valleys(path,typ,acc):

    df = pd.read_csv(path,index_col=False, names=['Timestamp', typ]).set_index('Timestamp')  #assuming you have two columns, the first of which is the timestamp
    n = acc
    df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df[typ].values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]][typ]
    df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df[typ].values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]][typ]
```